# É possível obter um atributo pai sendo que a classe define o atributo filho?

Tags: c#, atributos

Supondo que eu tenha a seguinte hierarquia:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class GrandpaAttribute : Attribute
{
    public GrandpaAttribute() {}
}

public class ParentAttribute() : GrandpaAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ParentAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ChildAttribute() : ParentAttribute
{
    public int Number { get; }

    public ChildAttribute(string name, int number) : base(name)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

Em determinada aplicação, eu uso o atributo `ChildAttribute`:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Child("The Beast", 666)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Surgiu a dúvida:

É possivel abstrair a herança entender que a propriedade `Description` possui o atributo `GrandpaAttribute`?

Minha intenção é obter uma instância de `GrandaAttribute` definida em uma propriedade da classe `Foo` como `ParentAttribute`, `ChildAttribute` ou qualquer outro atributo derivado dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você deseja, chegar na instância da classe `GrandpaAttribute`, por motivos de teste adicionei uma propriedade `First` para que o teste seja realizado, primeiro se busca a instância real, e depois com um `cast` chega na classe `GrandpaAttribute`, exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple=false, Inherited=true)]
public class GrandpaAttribute : Attribute
{
    public GrandpaAttribute() 
    {
        First = "Teste";
    }
    public string First {get;set;} 
}

public class ParentAttribute : GrandpaAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ParentAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ChildAttribute : ParentAttribute
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public ChildAttribute(string name, int number) 
        : base(name)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Child("The Beast", 666)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ChildAttribute childAttribute = typeof(Foo)
                .GetProperty("Description")
                .GetCustomAttribute<ChildAttribute>(true);      


        Console.WriteLine(((GrandpaAttribute)childAttribute).First);
    }
}
```

[Um exemplo OnLine DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/97jNHI)

Comment: Obrigado por checar, mas eu acho que não me expressei bem. Eu não quero ter que usar `GetCustomAttribute<ChildAttribute>`, pois no método que eu estou planejando não me interessa especificamente qual descendente de `GrandaAttribute` está definida, se é `Child` ou `Parent` ou alguma outra que eu criar depois... Vou editar a minha pergunta incluindo isso, é uma informação relevante que eu deixei passar.

Comment: Ababei de perceber que funciona! Usando seu exemplo no DotNetFiddle fiz a modificação do tipo `Child` para `Grandpa` e funcionou perfeitamente. Vou fazer essa edição e lhe garantir os créditos. Obrigado.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza fique um pouco sem entender, mas, qualquer coisa deixe uma explicação qual é o seu objetivo final

Comment: Ele apenas quer `.GetCustomAttribute<GrandpaAttribute>(true);` retorne também os `ChildAttribute`. @DiegoRafaelSouza  Isso funciona porque uma expressão: `(new ChildAttribute("",1) is GrandpaAttribute)` é verdadeira =]

Comment: pois é, eu fiquei me questionando se o código da pergunta já não estava funcionando... rs mas não tive como dar atenção